# Get gallery images from page ID

Tags: gallery, get-children

I have a page within WordPress called 'Gallery', the page ID is 128, and I need to display only the gallery images from that page on a different page with a different ID. The images were uploaded using the standard WordPress gallery functionality.

I've been trying to use `get_children` and a `foreach` loop to achieve it, but I can't seem to get only the gallery images from the page I need (ID 128).

Here's what I have so far:

```
$images = get_children( array( 
    'post_parent'    => 128, 
    'post_type'      => 'attachment', 
    'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order', 
    'order'          => 'ASC', 
    'numberposts'    => 999 
) ); 
if ( $images ) { 
    // looping through the images
    foreach ( $images as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'full' );
    }
}
```

How can I display gallery images from a WordPress page, on a different page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `get_post_galleries_images` function, which returns an array of all the galleries from whatever post ID you specify. The following is a quick function that will display all the images:

```
function na_get_gallery_image_urls( $post_id, $number = false ) {

    $post = get_post($post_id);
    $count = 0;

    // Make sure the post has a gallery in it
    if( ! has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'gallery' ) )
        return;

    // Retrieve all galleries of this post
    $galleries = get_post_galleries_images( $post );

    // Loop through all galleries found
    foreach( $galleries as $gallery ) {

        // Loop through each image in each gallery
        foreach( $gallery as $image ) {

            if ( $number == $count )
            return;

            echo '<img src="'.$image.'">';
            $count++;

        }

    }

 }
```

If you put that in your functions.php file, you could then call the function with the ID like this: na_get_gallery_image_urls(128).

Comment: Thanks Nate, that's a fantastic way to do it, It hadn't occurred to me it could even be done that way. Is there anyway I can limit the number of images that appear? I forgot to add that to my original question, sorry!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. I updated the code and added a "number" option. So if you only want 10 images, do na_get_gallery_image_urls(128, 10). If you don't specify an amount, it will return them all. @DavidAlsbright

Comment: Working perfectly, thanks again for your help, Nate. It's very much appreciated!